# What's the formula that relates capacitance, permittivity and geometric coefficient in the ring capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

I find it hard to calculate the geometric coefficient of a capacitor with two cylindric electrodes and a tiny distance between them, exactly like this one :

[image]

Does anybody know the exact formula?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the capacitnce between those two coppery looking electrodes, or the capacitance of each to an enclosing cylincrical sheild that you've removed so we can see what's inside?

Comment: The capacitance between the two electrodes.

Comment: Well that's a toughy, not least because the space between the electrodes is so open and filled with other stuff that will affect it. Even for just those electrodes in free space, you're looking at Bessel functions for the cylindrical-ness, and because they're edge-on to each other, Wierstrasse transformations (had to do a simpler geometry for work decades ago). You might make a very approximate start with the neutral plane between them, then an edge-above-ground transmission line, integrated round the circle. It's going to be horrible, however you try it.